# Oracle ID trigger inserts with ID that's already taken

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have a table in Oracle 12c which implements a sequence to increment ID's on inserts:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  
"ORCL_WD"."BIR_GRIDBASE_ID_SEQ"  
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 61 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

and the trigger for this:

```
create or replace trigger BIR_GRIDBASE_TRIG  
   before insert on "ORCL_WD"."BIR_GRIDBASE" 
   for each row 
begin  
   if inserting then 
      if :NEW."ID" is null then 
         select BIR_GRIDBASE_ID_SEQ.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
      end if; 
   end if; 
end;
```

This sequence works, but I have some gaps in my ID fields, so when inserting new items into this table, the insert duplicates ID's.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Does the trigger try to insert duplicate values, or is the issue in the fact that the trigger generates gaps?

Comment: `if :NEW."ID" is null then` - if its not `NULL` then it won't use the sequence value and will just insert whatever value the user proposed - the sequence won't know that this value has been used and will just try to use the next value in the sequence.

Comment: You do not need to drop into an SQL scope to get the next sequence value. You could just do: `:NEW.ID := BIR_GRIDBASE_ID_SEQ.nextval;`

Comment: @MT0 yes the values are null

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your last ID value in table
2. Check your status SEQUENCE

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM user_sequences 
   WHERE sequence_name = 'BIR_GRIDBASE_ID_SEQ';
   ```

Maybe you add value to this table without sequnce and now you have duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You include the line:

```
if :NEW."ID" is null then
```

This means that if the `ID` the user has tried to insert is not `NULL` then it will just continue using the user-proposed `ID` value and not the sequence value.

The simplest way to solve this is to not use a trigger and just include the sequence value in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO ORCL_WD.BIR_GRIDBASE (
  ID,
  COLUMN_A,
  COLUMN_B
) VALUES (
  ORCL_WD.BIR_GRIDBASE_ID_SEQ,
  'Value A',
  'Value B'
);
```

Then the user cannot propose id values and the id value will always be a distinct value.

If you are reliant on using the trigger then you should take a long look at whether it is necessary to allow the user to propose ID values and, if so, you will have to code defensively to prevent these duplicates occurring (i.e. skip some sequence values). If it isn't then you could just remove the `if :NEW."ID" is null then` statement like this:

```
create or replace trigger BIR_GRIDBASE_TRIG  
   before insert on "ORCL_WD"."BIR_GRIDBASE" 
   for each row 
begin  
  :NEW.ID := BIR_GRIDBASE_ID_SEQ.nextval; 
end;
/
```

and all the ID values will come from the sequence.

Comment: the value of the ID is null when going through the insert